# are STL Containers .push_back() naughty

Tags: c++, arrays, api, opengl

This might seem daft for which I'm sorry, I've been writing a bit some code for the Playstation 2 for uni. I am writing a sort of API for the Graphic Synthesizer. I am using a similar syntax to that of openGL which is a state machine.

So the input would something like

```
gsBegin(GS_TRIANGLE);

gsColor(...);
gsVertex3f(...);
gsVertex3f(...);
gsVertex3f(...);

gsEnd();
```

This is great so far for line/triangles/quads with a determined amount of vertices, however things like a `LINE_STRIP` or `TRIANGLE_FAN` take an undetermined amount of points. I have been warned off several times for using stl containers because of the push_back() method in this situation because of the time sensitive nature (is this justified).

If its not justified what would be a better way of dealing with the undetermined amount situation. Currently I have an Array that can hold 30 vertices at a time, is this best way of dealing with this kind of situation?

Comment: Where is any STL in your code?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more clear?

Comment: @Mark, there isn't any I'm using an array at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vector's `push_back` has amortized constant time complexity because it exponentially increases the capacity of the vector.  (I'm assuming you're using vector, because it's ideal for this situation.)  However, in practice, rendering code is very performance sensitive, so if the `push_back` causes a vector reallocation, performance may suffer.

You can prevent reallocations by reserving the capacity before you add to it.  If you call `myvec.reserve(10);`, you are guaranteed to be able to add 10 elements before the vector reallocates.

However, this still requires knowing ahead of time how many elements you need.  Also, if you create and destroy lots of different vectors, you're still doing a lot of memory allocation.  Instead, just use *one* vector for all vertices, and re-use it.  Calling `clear()` returns it to empty *while keeping its allocated capacity*.  This way you don't actually need to reserve anything - the first few times you use it it'll reallocate and grow, but once it reaches its peak size, it won't need to reallocate any more.  The nice thing about this is the vector finds the approximate size it needs to be, and once it's "warmed up" there's no further allocation so it is high performance.

In short:

- Use a single persistently stored `std::vector`
- `push_back` as much as you like
- When you're done, `clear()`.

In practice this will perform as well as a C array, but without a hard limit on size.

Comment: `resize(0)` didn't free memory on any STL implementation I've seen, and neither did `clear()` (in fact, I'd never expect it to do so since I like the advantage of having the memory there all the time). Can you confirm your claim somehow? The only way of releasing the memory I know is `std::vector<int>().swap(myvec);`.

Comment: I realise now that was only based on a vague memory, so I edited it out and just said to use `clear()`.  I think I might have got it from somewhere which said the standard permitted `clear()` to release memory, but no implementations did it...?  Could well be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

University, eh? Just tell them `push_back` has *amortized constant time complexity* and they'll be happy.

Comment: I should say it wasn't the uni that warned me off push_back(), but various unsubstantiated internet gossip, hence my curiosity.

Comment: @James: Faster than constant time? What is that, `O(McFly)`?

Comment: @FredOverflow: constant time with a lower constant, evidently.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yep. Besides, `O(McFly)` isn't faster, you just get to go back in time and pick the correct result. :)

Comment: @James: Ahh, lower latency but not lower resource utilization. Still, some unscrupulous individuals might like to use such a scheme, then sell the computer to some poor buyer who is unaware that all his compute cycles have already been used for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2):

First, avoid using `glBegin` / `glEnd` if you can, and instead use something like `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`.

`push_back()` on a `std::vector` is a quick operation unless the array needs to grow in size when the operation occurs.  Set the `vector` capacity as high as you think you will need it to be and you should see minimal overhead.  'Raw' arrays will usually always be slightly faster, but then you have to deal with using 'raw' arrays.

Comment: std::Vector should have the same performance as raw arrays if you use [] AND if you don't have range checking turned on in your compiler

Comment: @Martin Beckett: If he uses `[]`, yes, but he was asking about `push_back`, which I believe is slightly slower because it checks if it needs to regrow the array.

Comment: A primitive array will not be faster than a `std::vector` unless you know its size at compile-time and that size is fixed.

Comment: true, I meant once you have the data in the array - in general you shouldn't  think that vector is worse than an array.

Comment: Oh I don't think a vector is worse than an array - I pretty much never use a raw array unless I know for a fact that the maximum array size is set in stone.

Comment: @James, thanks. Since this not openGL but a Semi API for the PS2 I'm just mimicking some gl idioms.

Comment: @PhilCK: Ah.  Figured I could save you some costly function call overhead. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is always the alternative of using a `deque`.

A `deque` is very much like a `vector`, contiguity apart. Basically, it's often implemented as a `vector` of arrays.

This means a lower allocation cost, but member access might be slightly slower (though constant) because of the double dereference, so I am unsure if it's profitable in your case.

There is also the LLVM alternative: `SmallVector<T,N>`, which preallocates (right in the vector) space for `N` elements, and will simply get back to using a traditional vector-like implementation once the size has grown too much.

Answer (score 1):

The drawback to using `std::vector` in this kind of situation is making sure you manage your memory allocation properly.  On systems like the PS2 (PS3 seems to be a bit better at this), memory allocation is insanely slow and if you don't reserve the right amount of space in the vector to begin with (and it has to resize several times when adding items), you will slow your game to a creeping crawl.  If you know what your max size is going to be and reserve it when you create the vector, you won't have a problem.

That said, if this vector is going to be a temporary/local variable, you will still be reallocating memory every time your function is called.  So if this function is called every frame, you will still have the performance problem.  You can get around this by using a custom allocator and/or making the vector global (or a member variable to a class that will exist during your game loop).

Comment: Or static to the method. Depends on what's needed

Answer (score 1):

You can always equip the container you want to use with proper allocator, which takes into account the limitations of the platform and the expected grow/shrink scenarios etc...